# CSS Transition on open and close Menu in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-transitions

I have MenuBody component which is showed if state of isOpen is true. I want to add transition when menu is opening and also when is closing. Animation for opening is working but on closing it doesn't work.

This is my code

```
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
<button onClick={()=>setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>open menu</button>

       {isOpen ? <MenuBody /> : null}

    ....

    const MenuBody = () => {
    return (
     <div className={styles.menuBody}>
    //some content here to display when it's opened
    </div>
    )}
```

CSS

```
    @-webkit-keyframes menuBody {
        0%   { opacity: 0; }
        100% { opacity: 1; }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes menuBody {
        0%   { opacity: 0; }
        100% { opacity: 1; }
    }
    @-o-keyframes menuBody {
        0%   { opacity: 0; }
        100% { opacity: 1; }
    }
    @keyframes menuBody {
        0%   { opacity: 0; }
        100% { opacity: 1; }
    }
    .menuBody {
....
       -webkit-animation: menuBody 0.5s ease-in-out;
            -moz-animation: menuBody 0.5s ease-in-out;
            -o-animation: menuBody 0.5s ease-in-out;
            animation: menuBody 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
```

I would appreciate any kind of help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem might be in the way how you wrote `MenuBody` or in `isOpen` since you didn't provide any code regarding closing I am gonna assume, that maybe it's missing. So I would recommend adding some button into the `MenuBody` which will be able to change the state of `isOpen`.

**EDIT #1**

I would recommend adding and removing a class that says if Modal is open or closed. I would recommend using this method described here: https://erikmartinjordan.com/react-on-disappear-animation

Comment: I have button isOpen implemented edited the question.. you can take a look.. thanks

Comment: Then I would say it's because you are unmounting component from rendering before animation is able to do itself.

Comment: I edited my answer I recommend checking that link for an answer